# Div floating, postitioning

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have such html code:

```
<body style="text-align: center;">
<div style="background-color: #014156; text-align: center; width: 985px; margin:6px auto;">
<div style="background-color: #a6a6a6; width: 975px; background-image:url('shadow.gif'); background-repeat:repeat-x; background-position: center top; margin: 6px; overflow:hidden;">
<div style="float:left; width: 674px; text-align: center; color:#056c02; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 20opx;" title="Product title"><span style="color: #d2ff00">"</span><span style="background-color: #d2ff00">[[Title]]</span><span style="color: #d2ff00">"</span><p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 5px;" title="Description">[[Description]]</p></div>
<div style="float:left; width: 301px; text-align: center; " title="General information (Image, stock, price)">[[Picture1]]<BR><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 9px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">Image is for illustrative purposes only. Please refer to product description.</SPAN></div>
</div>
```

Which results:

[image]

In Gray backgrounded div I need that two divs would align inline, and result would be like this:
[image]

What should I change, where is the problem?

P.s. my styles is described in tags because I dont have ability to use css for this because of some host reasons. So please don't start telling me about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lower the width of either the left div or the right div.

Lowering the first div to `650px` for example fixes the problem.

Your logic was right: 674px + 301px does equal 975px but you didn't account for margins and padding and borders in those values.  Make the "real" width less than or equal to 975px

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. :)

Comment: @Tautvydas If the problem is fixed an upvote + marking the answer as correct would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `float: left`, try with `display: inline-block`, that should work.

Comment: Don't you need to align both divs in the same line instead of one below the other? Or what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `p` tag which is a `block` lined up next to and inline `span`.  Add either `inline` or `inline-block` to the `p` tag, depending on your requirements.  Another possibility is you could change the `p` to a `span`.